# Converting NMR ascii file to peak list

Tags: r, bioinformatics, spectrum

I have some Bruker NMR spectra that i am using to create a program as part of a project. My program needs to work on the actual spectrum. So i converted the 1r files of the Bruker NMR spectra to ASCII. For Carnitine this is what the ascii file looks like(this is not the complete list. The complete list runs into thousands of lines. This is only a snapshot):

```
-0.807434   -23644  
-0.807067   -22980  
-0.806701   -22967  
-0.806334   -24513  
-0.805967   -27609  
-0.805601   -31145  
-0.805234   -33951  
-0.804867   -35553  
-0.804501   -35880  
-0.804134   -35240  
-0.803767   -34626  
-0.8034  -34613 
-0.803034   -34312  
-0.802667   -32411  
-0.8023  -28925 
-0.801934   -25177  
-0.801567   -22132  
-0.8012  -19395
```

and this is what the spectrum is: [image]
<sub>(source: [wisc.edu](http://www.bmrb.wisc.edu/metabolomics/standards/L_carnitine/nmr/bmse000211/spectra_png/1H.png))</sub>

**My program has to identify the peaks from this data. So i need to know how to interpret these numbers. And how exactly they are converted into their appropriate values in the spectrum.** So far this is what i have learnt:

1.) The first column represents the spectral point position (ppm)

2.) The second column represents the intensity of each peak.

3.) notice that in the second column there are some numbers which are not perfectly aligned but are closer to the first column. Eg:-34613, -28925, -19395. I think this is significant.

For the sake of full disclosure- I am doing the programming in R.

NOTE: I have also asked this in Biostar but i think i have a better chance of getting an answer here than there because not many people seem to be answering questions there.

EDIT: This is one solution that i have found is plausible:

A friend gave me the idea to use an awk script to check where exactly the intensities in the file change from positive to negative to find the local maxima. Here is a working script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{dydx = 0;}
{ 
  if(NR > 1)
     { dydx = ($2 - y0)/($1 - x0); } 
  if(NR > 2 && last * dydx < 0)
     { printf( "%.4f  %.4f\n", (x0 + $1)/2, log((dydx<0)?-dydx:dydx)); } ;
  last=dydx; x0=$1; y0=$2
}' /home/chaitanya/Work/nmr_spectra/caffeine/pdata/1/spectrumtext.txt  | awk '$2 > 17'
```

Tell me if you dont understand it. I will improve the explanation.

Also, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075208/awk-script-in-r) related question i asked.

Comment: I don't see why you need an `awk` script to do this simple task if you're going to perform the rest of your analysis in R. Why not learn how to code this idea in R?

Comment: It can be done in R yes. And i will probably end up coding it in R. My code will probably be faster too if coded in R. This is just something that came up while discussing with a friend and i wanted to know if it can be done this way.

Comment: @baptiste Off topic question- Why is the word Work in my code blue in color?

Comment: dunno, my guess is that the first letter is capitalized and the syntax highlighter thinks it's some kind of a class or something. Or perhaps it's a subtle subliminal hint that we should get back to Work.

Comment: wrt 3): there is no need to worry about the spaces (are they actually spaces or is it a single tab instead?). In either case, `read.table` imports the data easily, and if you want to have additional possibilities of handling the spectra, you can have a look at package hyperSpec (which doesn't do peak finding, but all kinds of plotting of spectra etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a worked example with a reproducible piece of code. I don't claim it's any good with regard to the strategy or coding, but it could get you started.

```
find_peaks <- function (x, y, n.fine = length(x), interval = range(x), ...) {
  maxdif <- max(diff(x)) # longest distance between successive points

  ## selected interval for the search
  range.ind <- seq(which.min(abs(x - interval[1])),
                   which.min(abs(x - interval[2])))
  x <- x[range.ind]
  y <- y[range.ind]

  ## smooth the data
  spl <- smooth.spline(x, y, ...)
  ## finer x positions
  x.fine <- seq(range(x)[1], range(x)[2], length = n.fine)
  ## predicted y positions
  y.spl <- predict(spl, x.fine, der = 0)$y
  ## testing numerically the second derivative
  test <- diff(diff((y.spl), 1) > 0, 1)
  maxima <- which(test == -1) + 1

  ## according to this criterion, we found rough positions
  guess <- data.frame(x=x.fine[maxima], y=y.spl[maxima])

  ## cost function to maximize 
  obj <- function(x) predict(spl, x)$y

  ## optimize the peak position around each guess
  fit <- data.frame(do.call(rbind,
          lapply(guess$x, function(g) {
            fit <- optimize(obj, interval = g + c(-1,1) * maxdif, maximum=TRUE)
            data.frame(x=fit$maximum,y=fit$objective)
          })))

  ## return both guesses and fits
  invisible(list(guess=guess, fit=fit))
}

set.seed(123)
x <- seq(1, 15, length=100)
y <- jitter(cos(x), a=0.2)

plot(x,y)
res <- find_peaks(x,y)
points(res$guess,col="blue")
points(res$fit,col="red")
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 2):

Package [PRocess has a function to find peaks](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/PROcess/inst/doc/howtoprocess.pdf) in spectra. There are many more, if you search for something like "peak finding R"

Comment: This seems to be a good resource. But i would still like to know if possible how exactly the information in the ascii file is mapped on to the spectrum.

Comment: there's been a whole recent issue of the R journal dedicated to magnetic resonance imaging; I reckon you could get some context by reading through a selection of the articles.

Comment: All i find when i search for Peak finding R is mail archives which specify algorithms and Matlab packages. Any suggestion?

Comment: Both `RSiteSearch` and `sos::findFn` give me promising results with search terms like "peak find" or "peak detect"