# Awk script in R

Tags: r, awk

I need to run an awk script to detect local maxima(peaks) in a spectrum. This spectrum is in the form of two columns in a text file.

This is part of a larger project which will identify whether these peaks represent certain compounds(metabolites really).

I have searched on Google and myriad other places i really cant find anything for running awk scripts in R.

EDIT: The awk script i am using looks something like this-

```
awk 'BEGIN{dydx = 0;}
{ 
  if(NR > 1)
     { dydx = ($2 - y0)/($1 - x0); } 
  if(NR > 2 && last * dydx < 0)
     { printf( "%.4f  %.4f\n", (x0 + $1)/2, log((dydx<0)?-dydx:dydx)); } ;
  last=dydx; x0=$1; y0=$2
}' /home/chaitanya/Work/nmr_spectra/caffeine/pdata/1/spectrumtext.txt  | awk '$2 > 17'
```

You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060569/converting-nmr-ascii-file-to-peak-list) question i had asked yesterday. Please note it is NOT the same question.

Comment: are you [asking the same question as yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9060569/471093)?

Comment: @baptiste Not really the same question. No. I have found one solution for yesterday's problem. And i am trying to make it work. I am still looking for other possible solutions. So please dont consider this a duplicate and down vote this or the other question out of that reason.

Comment: it's just not clear if you actually followed up on yesterday's idea. If you found a solution, please add it to the discussion, and explain better the real problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @baptiste is right (as always). You should always be transparent. Post as much information as you can and link to any relevant material.

Comment: @baptiste I changed both the questions. Please have a look. I think they are pretty clear right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should be able to do

```
system('your awk command here')
```

If you have single quotes in your `awk` command, either do as Hong Ooi suggests and put your `awk` command in a separate file and then just run that from the `system` command or escape the single quotes:

```
> system('echo \'hello guy!\' ')
hello guy!
```

Comment: That wont work. My awk script uses " and '. So it clashes with the quotes used in the system(' ') command.

I have edited the question to include the awk script.

Comment: @guy: you put the filename of your awk script in the `system()` call.

Comment: I agree with @HongOoi . I edited the answer to incorporate HongOoi's suggestion.

Comment: oh yeah! i forgot i could escape the characters.

Answer (score 3):

Update for Windows 10 users now able to use AWK natively:

To Windows 10 users with WSL (windows subsystem for linux) installed, you can run AWK in windows from an R console with:

```
>  system( 'wsl awk \'BEGIN { print "Hello, world" }\' ')
Hello, world
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have reasonably smooth spectral data, there are several functions available which do a good job of locating local maxima and minima (aka "peaks").  I like the tools in `pastecs` , but take a look at the following packages (in my rough order of choice) :

`pastecs,

Peaks,

seewave,

ppc`

Comment: interesting, thanks for the list. I've only ever used PRocess and custom functions, I should check these out.